# How to setup live ubuntu server?

Tags: webserver

I have set up my Ubuntu server on VirtualBox and now I want to take it live. I've registered a free domain (My Dot TK domain, for testing purposes before I purchase the real deal) but now it requires FORWARD URL.... Do I use my external (public) IP address or what? And what do I set up in my router — is there a particular port that I should open, for example? I am really a newbie at all this. Please help. Thanks!

My server:
IP address: 192.168.0.33
Broadcast address: 192.168.0.255

Comment: is your question answered? If so, you should consider selecting a correct answer to close this question, and so that other also know what the right answer is.

Answer (score 1):

These IP addresses are [private IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) ­— that is, they can be used only in a private network. To take your website public you have to obtain a public IP address from a service provider. After that, you will have to register an Host (A) DNS record, aka a Forward DNS record, also from a service provider.

About configuring a router, Do you have a firewall/router? Or you need to set up your Ubuntu server as your router?

About ports, what is the use of this server? If you want it to be a web server, you will have to forward port 80 on your firewall. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should give the server a static internal ip-adres:

Edit /etc/network/interfaces (see the iface eth0 part)

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

so that it looks like:

  `auto eth0`
  `iface eth0 inet static`
  `address 192.168.1.23   # Your ip address here`
  `netmask 255.255.255.224 # Your netmask here`
  `gateway 192.168.1.1     # Your gate address here`
  `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4  # Google's nameservers`


After that either restart or do the following:

    `sudo ifdown eth0`
    `sudo ifup eth0`

 Found [here](http://bruceshankle.blogspot.nl/2012/05/how-to-add-static-ip-and-dns-to-ubuntu.html).

MAKE SURE you don't use an already used internal ip, so just make it something like 192.168.1.200.

Now you log in to your modem, and add a virtual server, let it point to the new internal ip you set for the server. Open the correct ports and you should be ready to go.
If your modem doesn't support a virtual server, just open the required ports.
The default website port is 80. But at dot.tk you can always say, refer to external-ip:port.

I hope this helped, and you can always ask when this isn't clear enough(since its a wall of text).

Have a nice day